# When I press "Run" on Android Studio, it opens up the background picture in the drawable folder

Tags: android, jpeg, drawable

When I have nothing in my drawable folder, the app runs fine on my phone. However, when there is a jpeg file in the drawable folder, whether or not I have the android:background="@drawable/jpeg" code, Android Studio simply opens the picture of the jpeg in another tab. How do I stop it doing that and run the app as before on my phone?

Comment: what tab?  where did you put the background drawable? can you provide some code? Is really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I put the background picture in the drawable folder found in "...app\src\main\res\drawable". Whenever a jpeg file is in that folder, Android Studio simply opens up the picture and does not continue to run.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, the files name has to be all lowercased for it to work.

Comment: Good job. Helped me alot. Thank you.